# Set TEMP & TMP on Current User through Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch

I am in an IT lock-down situation so I have limited access to things. I am trying to run the latest version of [Portable Google Chrome 6](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable). It won't let me install extensions and I think it's because I can't access my TEMP and TMP files, and for other reasons as well, I want to be able to change the temp variables with my daily run [batch file](http://code.google.com/p/callcenterprogram/downloads/list). My code works fine but works only when my CMD window is open:

```
:T
CALL :TEMP
GOTO CHOICE

:TEMP
ECHO.Remaping TMP Drive
IF NOT EXIST %HOMEDRIVE%\jnk MD %HOMEDRIVE%\jnk
SET TMP=%HOMEDRIVE%\jnk
SET TEMP=%HOMEDRIVE%\jnk
ECHO.TEMP=%TEMP% and TMP=%TMP%
ECHO.Done.
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

So I am reading [these tips](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) and I just can't get it. How can I check where System variable are stored for my Current User (HKCU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HKCU\Environment\`

```
reg add HKCU\Environment /v TEMP /t REG_SZ /d "%%HOMEDRIVE%%%%HOMEPATH%%\Temporary"
```

Comment: This looks like what I was about to try can add rewrite a value that already exists?

Comment: @lazfish: yes, add `/f`

Comment: OK Looks like it works but when I ECHO.%TMP% and %TEMP% I still get the default. So I go to change it with:
reg add "hklm\system\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v TEMP /t REG_SZ /d "%%HOMEDRIVE%%%%HOMEPATH%%\jnk" /f
reg add "hklm\system\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v TMP /t REG_SZ /d "%%HOMEDRIVE%%%%HOMEPATH%%\jnk" /f
Instead and I get Access is denied.

Comment: The `reg add` call won't modify the env var values in your current shell, just values for new shells. You'll still need the `set TEMP=...` calls to see the changes in your current shell.

Comment: I noticed that. It it looks like the TEMP & TMP paths are using the Machine location instead of local user because even new shells show default for ECHO.%TMP%
IT has got me. What can I say?

Comment: @lazfish: The new shells inherit environment from their parent process (usually `explorer.exe`). Log out to make sure all changes propagate.

Comment: @lazfish: Also, _do not change_ the system-wide environment. You say you're in a locked down enviroment; you have been given `HKCU` as the location of user-local environment; why are you ignoring it and mucking with `HKLM`?

Comment: I am just trying to get my TMP files available to me.  So if I get the TMP files to say they have been updated I would need to kill and restart explore.exe to see the changes in CMD prompt when I run ECHO.%TEMP%?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make permanent changes to environment variables is: Control Panel > System > Advanced tab > Environment variables.  The upper section contains variables for the current user.

Comment: Can't access, also I would have to do it everyday.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [SetEnv tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/SetEnv.aspx) from BAT scripts to make permanent changes to environment variables. Works well. It's a shame it's not part of the Windows OS install. It's worked all the way to Vista for me. I haven't tried it in Windows 7.

Comment: SETX is standard on Vista/Win7 (and in the WinServer resource tools for earlier versions).